# How to get properties from a survey's rating scale(Graphical responses view) response

Tags: search-results, survey-list, survey, rating

i have created a survey list with different questions, one of these is a rating scale type, with 5 different questions that have a different values (from 1 to 5)

how can i get these information? I need them for add in a content search , **where i filter data that comes from SharePoint 2013 searcher**

now i get other data from survey list by a mapping with refinableString of crawled properties that survey response create